# Validate all cloudformation files in a s3 folder

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, boto3, aws-cli

CloudFormation validate supports validating a cloudformation template in s3.
How to validate all files in a s3 location. The files are located in a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below `python` script to validate all cloudformation template in s3 bucket/folder
The below script generates `Object Url`/`Public Url` of all files in a s3 folder and then passes the url to `validate_file` function

```py
import boto3

s3_uri="s3://BUCKET_NAME/FOLDER_1/FOLDER2/" # S3 URI of the folder you want to recursively scan, Replace this with your own S3 URI

# Split the s3 uri to extract bucket name and the file prefix
# Splitting S# 3 URI will generate an array
# Combine the appropirate elements of the array to extraxt BUCKET_NAME and PREFIX
arr=s3_uri.split('/')
bucket =arr[2]
prefix=""
for i in range(3,len(arr)-1):
    prefix=prefix+arr[i]+"/"
    
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
    
def validate_file(object_url): # function to validate cloudformation template
    cloudformation_client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
    
    response = cloudformation_client.validate_template(
        TemplateURL=object_url
    )
    print(response) # print the response
    

def get_all_s3_files(bucket,prefix,s3_client): # generate object url of all files in the folder and pass it to validate function

    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket,  Prefix=prefix) # Featch Meta-data of all the files in the folder
    files = response.get("Contents")
    for file in files: # Iterate through each files
        file_path=file['Key']
        object_url="https://"+bucket+".s3.amazonaws.com/"+file_path #create Object URL  Manually
        print("Object Url =  "+object_url)
        if object_url.endswith(".yml"):
            validate_file(object_url=object_url) # validate all files

get_all_s3_files(bucket=bucket,prefix=prefix,s3_client=s3_client)
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it with BASH

This example assumes you have aws cli and jq cli tools installed. It also assumes your cloud formation files are uploaded to s3.

```
BUCKET_NAME="bucket-name-here"
TEMPLATE_FOLDER="cloudformation/templates"

objects=$(aws s3api list-objects --bucket $BUCKET_NAME --prefix $TEMPLATE_FOLDER --query "Contents[].Key" --output json)


for file in $(echo $objects | jq -r '.[]'); do
  if [[ $file == *.yml ]] then;
    TEMPLATE_URL="https://${BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file}"
    echo "URL: $TEMPLATE_URL"
    aws cloudformation validate-template --template-url "${TEMPLATE_URL}" 1>/dev/null
  fi
done
```